# Алгоритм тетрации

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, математика

**Тетрация** - это математическая операция, которая является более высоким уровнем возведения в степень, чем возведение в степень или даже двойная степень. Если возведение в степень позволяет умножать число на само себя определенное количество раз, и двойная степень позволяет это делать многократно, то тетрация позволяет повторять этот процесс множество раз.

Пример: Если мы возведем число в тетрацию, скажем, 3 в тетрации 3, это означает, что мы возведем 3 в степень 3, затем возведем полученный результат в степень 3 снова, и так далее многократно. Это операция с экспонентами, которая растет очень быстро и приводит к огромным числам. Тетрация используется в математике и теории чисел для описания более сложных операций возведения в степень.

Существует следующий алгоритм тетрации на Python, использующий рекурсию:

```
def tetration(a, n):
    if n == 1:
        return a
    else:
        return a ** tetration(a, n - 1)
```

Данный алгоритм является слишком медленным и требует использования `set_int_max_str_digits`

Использование:

```
base = 3
iterations = 3
result = tetration(base, iterations)
print(f"{base} тетрация {iterations} равна {result}")
```

Вывод в терминале

```
3 тетрация 3 равна 7625597484987
```

Существуют ли другие алгоритмы тетрации или библиотеки предоставляющие данную операцию в более ускоренном виде?

---

UPD

Из комментария [@StanislavVolodarskiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/416121/stanislav-volodarskiy) следует, что проблема не в алгоритме, а в скорости вывода, в таком случае необходимо рассмотреть решение, при котором скорость вывода была бы быстрее, чем через `print()`

Comment: Ассоциация по [следующему вопросу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963477/is-there-an-efficient-implementation-of-tetration)

Comment: Каково практическое применение, зачем нужны тетрированные числа сами по себе?

Comment: @MBo практического - вот убей не придумаю. Но познавательного - много

Comment: Ну на мой взгляд - это такой объект, который записать в виде 5^^5 и только так и рассматривать. Значения большинства таких объектов всё равно необозримы.

Comment: Если нужен порядок значения — может, логарифмировать? Если типа "последняя цифра" — то операции по модулю? А точное значение — вряд ли оно кого-то интересует, и вряд ли его можно вычислить быстрее...

Comment: Почему вы думаете что ваш алгоритм медленный? Он один из самых быстрых. Но есть нюанс. Тетрация вычисляется быстро. Но питон медленно печатает большие целые. Например, `n = 7 ** 7 ** 7` вычислится почти мгновенно. А если вы захотите преобразовать его в строку или напечатать надо будет подождать секунд десять. И дело не в объеме печати. Попробуйте `print(len(str(n)))`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Значит проблема получается в скорости вывода, нужно отредактировать вопрос...

Comment: Если хотите быструю печать и более быстрые операции с целыми ставьте [gmpy2](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Заглушка на длину целого связана с квадратичной от логарифма числа сложностью печати. Хотите сделаться контрибьютором Питон? Попробуйте реализовать преобразование `int` -> `str` быстрее чем за квадрат. Алгоритмы известны.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy реально шустрее начал работать, красивое, использовал `gmpy2.digits(n)`

Comment: Только помните что это больше баловство. У вас появится аппетит к большим числам и очень скоро кончится память.